# Sound defaulting to HDMI

Tags: sound

I would like to know how to deafult my sound to always use headphones? 
I plug my laptop via display port into an external monitor. Whenever I restart ubuntu (13.04) the sound is always defaulted to HDMI/DisplayPort.

Is there a way to override this?

My Sound options are

1) HDMI/Displayport (Built-in-Audio)

2) Headphones (Built-in-Audio)